# How to fix ogg tags?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, tagging

I am searching a command-line tagging tool that supports ogg-tagging and allows to change encoding to the tags.

Comment: Why not use `vorbiscomment`?

Comment: You could try using ffmpeg. If not, vorbiscomment and lltag should work.

Answer (score 3):

As @LiveWireBT said in a comment, you can use `vorbiscomment`, available in the `vorbis-tools` package.

`vorbiscomment` is not really easy to use when you want to replace/edit a single tag, like Genre, because you have only two options: append a tag with `-a`, or replace ALL TAGS with `-w`.

Appending a Genre tag will ADD a Genre tag, not edit the current one.
Writing a Genre tag will ONLY write the Genre tag, and remove all other tags.

So my workaround to modify a tag is the following:

```
# dynamically: list tags, edit one with sed, rewrite tags
vorbiscomment -l file.ogg | sed 's/^genre=.*/GENRE=Black Metal/' | vorbiscomment -w file.ogg

# with a temporary file (it's actually one of the examples in the manpage)
# (a bit longer/more difficult to use in a for loop,
# since you can specify only one input file)
vorbiscomment -l file.ogg > comments.txt
<edit comments.txt with vim/nano/sed>
vorbiscomment -w -c comments.txt file.ogg
```

About the encoding of tags, the `--raw` option might be what you need:

> -R, --raw
>   Read and write comments in UTF-8, rather than converting to the user's character set.

Answer (score 0):

[**tageditor**](https://github.com/Martchus/tageditor) supports a wide variety of **formats**, and has both a **GUI** and **CLI** interface.

```
tageditor set \
    album="${album}" \
    artist="${artist}" \
    title="${title}" \
    genre="${genre}" \
    --files "${file}"
```